# Datatable scrollbar scrolling is table column

Tags: jquery, datatable, frontend

The scrollbar here also scrolls the column headers of the datatable. I don't want this. I just want the lines in the table to shift

https://prnt.sc/12l1zoi

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="table-responsive" style="height: 288px;">
        <table id="@String.Format(_id+"TabAuthorizersTable")" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" primarycolumn="AuthorizedCode" parameter="AuthorizersTable" style="width:100%">
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No image, add your code in snippet plz

Comment: I added a photo. I want the scroll bar to be inside the table, not the outermost, and only scrolling the table data.

Comment: Post your code ! html / css, whatever...

Comment: my code only this